# Deleting string from UIPicker upon selection

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uipickerview

I am creating a booking app. I am using UIPickers to display open times. I have the pickers fully functional but am not sure how to delete booked times after a user has selected one from the choices provided. I am relatively new to Xcode, so any information is greatly appreciated!!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class sTimeSelectionViewController:UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    let pickerData = ["9:30","10:30","11:30","12:30","1:30","2:30"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myPicker.dataSource = self
        myPicker.delegate = self
        myPicker.tag = 1
    }
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        myLabel.text = pickerData[row]
    }
    @IBAction func postData(sender: AnyObject) {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("deleted URL")
        ref.child("Time").setValue(myLabel.text)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First change your pickerData declaration from constant to variable

```
var pickerData = ["9:30","10:30","11:30","12:30","1:30","2:30"].
```

Next you would need to remove the array element in your method didSelectRow after your myLabel.text code

```
pickerData.removeAtIndex(row)
```

and reload your picker

```
myPicker.reloadAllComponents()
```

Comment: Hi Leo. Thanks for your code!! I have one question. I have added your code to my project and the data is deleting itself before the row is selected with a button push (as you brush over available times the data deletes itself as you scroll). Any idea on how this can be fixed??